# SQLite3 and "cascade" SELECTion

Tags: sql, select, join, sqlite

I have a parent table and a child table related to the parent table by some REFERENCE.

Suppose I exec a SELECT statement on the child and that it returns the at least one result. Can I arrange for my search to automatically yield all the content of all related parents with this child too?

Or must I always take the reference from the child and put this in a second SELECT statement and exec this myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use subqueries:

```
SELECT *
FROM Parent
WHERE Parent.Id IN (SELECT ParentId
                    FROM Child
                    WHERE Whatever_was_your_original_query)
```

Or a good old join:

```
SELECT Parent.*
FROM Parent INNER JOIN Child ON Parent.Id = Child.ParentId
WHERE Whatever_you_want_to_query
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the very basic purpose of SQL.  You will JOIN the two tables together to create one set of result rows with some or all columns from BOTH tables included.

For more info, see [this page](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html).